# "The behavior of `attribute_changed?` inside of after callbacks" After a basic `save`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is my hook method called after `after_create :set_after_create` in a model.

```
  def set_after_create
    passphrase = "#{id}+#{Time.zone.now.to_date}#{Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base}"
    update(
      ref: CryptLib.sha1(passphrase),
      token_key: CryptLib.sha1("#{passphrase}+#{Random.rand(20)}")
    )
  end
```

Now, I get a warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `attribute_changed?` inside of
>   after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new
>   return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after
>   `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To
>   maintain the current behavior, use `saved_change_to_attribute?`
>   instead. (called from set_after_create at
>   /app/app/models/project.rb:330)

I don't understand the connection between the alert and the method.

PS: I get no warning using the `update_columns` method, but I don't think that's the right way.

Config: Rails 5.1.4 and all gems updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `attribute_changed?` at some other place in the same model.
Method `attribute_changed?` will deprecate in rails newer versions. So, instead of using `attribute_changed?`, use `will_save_change_to_attribute?`
For more details see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord%2Flib%2Factive_record%2Fattribute_methods%2Fdirty.rb) .